# How to demangle C++ in GCC 2.96

Tags: c++, gcc

When I compile the code with `cxxabi.h`, I got this error:

> $g++ -g -o bt bt.cpp linux.cpp -rdynamic -fnew-abi
>
> cc1plus: -fnew-abi not supported in gcc-2.96-RH

[PS: I need do this in the source code, not c++filt bin tool!]

Thanks in advance.

Dma

Comment: @Paul R: thanks, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Why are you using GCC 2.96? http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-2.96.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-fnew-abi` flag was marked as experimental and subject to undocumented changes. Why are you using it? It's likely that (consistently!) removing it will allow you to rebuild everything.